# Ratio of expected values

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let's say that I have random variables, $A$ and $B$, and, given $N$ events, $B$ is a count of things that are a subset of what $A$ is a count of.  Can I use $\frac{\mathbb{E}[B]}{\mathbb{E}[A]}$ as the probability of $B$ given $A$?  Note that I am *not* asking about $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{B}{A}\right]$, which I do not believe you can get an expectation for.  However, it seems to me that since $\mathbb{E}[B]$ and $\mathbb{E}[A]$ are both deterministic values, then $\frac{\mathbb{E}[B]}{\mathbb{E}[A]}$ should be as well, and should in fact refer to the probability of $B$ given $A$.

If you need a concrete example, let's say that, for each time period, I can either throw a dice or not throw a dice, and $A$ represents the number of times I throw the dice for $N$ time periods.  Then, on my roll, I can get a 6 or not get a 6, and $B$ represents the number of times that I get a 6. Therefore, if I know the expected totals of each, I can calculate the probability of whether I get a 6 if the dice is rolled by the ratio of the expected value.

Is this correct or incorrect?

Comment: I think you need to read a proper textbook on probability theory because you do not seem to understand the terminology. *Outcomes* are elements of the sample space. *Stochastic processes* are collections of random variables indexed by time. *Expectation* is an operation on *random variables,* which are measurable functions defined on the sample space. It doesn't make any sense to call the "result" of a stochastic process an "outcome," or to take the expectation of an "outcome."

Comment: What would happen if the expectation of $A$ was $0$? For instance, what if $A$ was a random variable modeling someone's height difference from the overall average?

Comment: @Math1000 You are correct that my terminology is imprecise.  I will try to correct it, but I thought that my meaning was clear.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery - if the expectation was 0, then the result would be undefined, like any division by zero.  Remember, B is a subset of A, so I'm not sure what subset your example would refer to.  However, in my example, let's say that the expectation of # of dice rolls is 0.  Then the number of times that A is rolled given B would simply be undefined in this situation.

Comment: $E[X]$ is the expected value for some random variable.  For example, suppose I measure the heights of students in the class and find that the average height is 5'6".  Measuring a subset, the boys, I get an average height of 5'9".  $E[X] = 66, E[Y] = 69,$   The ratios $\frac {69}{66}$ or $\frac {66}{69}$ do NOT indicate the conditional probability that any boy will be taller (or shorter) than the class average.

Comment: Have you seen conditional probability yet https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability ?

Comment: @DougM - while what you say is true, I don't think it is exactly analogous to the situation I am describing.  In the case I am describing, as it says in the question, B is a count of things that A is a count of.  Let's take your example.  If the expected total of the inches of all of the students is, say, 3,0000.  Then, let's say the expected total of the inches of just the boys is 2,000.  Then, indeed, I would say that, given a particular inch, the probability that this particular inch belongs to a boy is 2/3.  Would this be correct or incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

$\mathsf E(B)/\mathsf E(A)$ is a constant.   $\mathsf P(B=b\mid A=a)$ is a function whose value depends on the parameters $a,b$ and the joint distribution of the random variables.   Generally, they should *not be equal*.

Answer (score 1):

As @Math1000 says, the terminology used in your question makes the question nonsense. "Probabilities of random variables" are not a thing.

To write $P(A)$ and $P(B)$, we need $A$ and $B$ to be *events*. That is, they are not measurements like "he is 1.56 meters tall" or "I rolled a 3 on this dice", but boolean ("yes/no", "true/false") outcomes of some real-world process. For example, an event could be "I went to work today" or "I rolled a 5 on this 6-sided die", or even "3 of the 10 dice rolls were even numbers".

By contrast, random variables are functions which describe a certain measurement associated with each possible outcome. For example, the following can all be described by random variables:

- How tall is this person?
- How many times did you go to work this week?
- What value did you roll on the die?
- How many of your 10 dice rolls were even?

Formally, the probability function $P$ is a measure on the set of events, and so expressions like $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are well-defined, where $A$ and $B$ are *events*, not random variables. In order to get the probability of making a certain measurement, we need to construct an event from a random variable, and then take the probability of that event.

For example, consider the probability space of rolling two fair 3-sided dice together. Then the sample space $\Omega$ is the set

$$
\begin{align}
\big\{ & (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), \\
       & (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), \\
       & (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)  \big\},
\end{align}
$$

where each element of the sample space is a pair whose elements describe the roll of the first die and the second die, in that order. Each element of this set is called an *outcome*, and an *event* is a set of outcomes. An event is said to occur if one of the outcomes it consists of occurs. Here, we see that, for any $\omega \in \Omega$, if we let $E = \{\omega\}$ be an event, then $P(E) = \frac{1}{9}$ (by definition, since there are 9 possible outcomes and the dice are fair).

A random variable is a function which takes an outcome as input, and outputs the associated measurement. Consider the random variable $X$ which describes the total/sum of a combined roll of these two dice. Then, for example, $X(1,3) = 4$, $X(2,1) = 3$, etc.. In order to construct an event from $X$, we need to consider a particular value that the dice roll total might be. Then an event $E$ like "The total of the roll is 4" can be constructed as

$$E := \big\{ \omega \in \Omega \:\big|\: X(\omega) = 4 \big\}.$$

The probability of this event is then $P(E)$; or, written in full,

$$P \bigg( \big\{ \omega \in \Omega \:\big|\: X(\omega) = 4 \big\} \bigg).$$

However, such expressions quickly become horribly tedious to write and interpret, so we just use expressions like $X=4$ and $P(X=4)$ as shorthand for these, respectively. Expressions like $P(X)$ don't mean anything.

---

> Let's say that I have random variables, $A$ and $B$, and, given $N$ events, $B$ is a count of things that are a subset of what $A$ is a count of.

It now rests upon you to try and clarify what you mean by this, if you think that the question you have in mind still makes sense. However, I shall try and interpret as best as I can for now.

Let $M$ be a set of all of the potential measurements of some quantity. Let $X: \Omega \to M$ and $Y: \Omega \to M$ be random variables such that, for all $\omega \in \Omega$, we have $X(\omega) \leq Y(\omega)$. Thus, in some sense, $X$ counts a subset of what $Y$ counts. Do you then ask the following question?

$$\text{For all }m \in M, \text{ is it true that }\frac{E(X)}{E(Y)} = P\big(X=m \:\big|\: Y=m\big)?$$

If not, then I reckon that clarifying what you mean by "$X$ is a count of things that are a subset of what $Y$ is a count of" in more formal, well-defined terms would likely make your question easily answerable.